# how does py2app add custom modules

Tags: flask, module, dependencies, pyinstaller, py2app

I try to create from a python script using flask framework a standalone mac app with py2app. The application uses the framework [pyfladesk](https://github.com/smoqadam/PyFladesk) for render website within a desktop window. On testing everything works fine, but as soon as I try to deploy the app with py2app , the  folders get bundled and the app is created. But as soon as I start the app, it halts. Looking in terminal it shows a ModuleNotFoundError. The module pyfladesk is not found.
How do I add 3 party modules to a py2app project. I tried the same procedure with pyinstaller as well with the same result.

Note: the module was added with pip3 and is located inside the venv of the given folder.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue, it turns out, py2app does not rely on the dependencies from venv, but rather on the installed one. 
Solution: `pip3 install pyfladesk` and all other used packages
update dependency search path in setup.py:

`OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'packages': ['requests', 'jinja2', 'pyfladesk']
           }`

Comment: Thanks! I've been struggling with this issue for more than 2 hours!